# How do I Include a .dll in compilation to avoid dynamic linking?

Tags: c#, dll

I am using a third party dll file which is referenced within a visual studio project using C#. In previous experiences on other projects, I was able to load objects from different dlls using dllImport, then create objects as if the source code of the dll was included in my project. However, that method is not working with the 3rd part dll. The program works flawlessly on the computer I am programming it on, however, when I run it on a different computer, it cannot find the dll. Is there a method to include the dll compiling and avoid using dynamic linking?

Comment: Generally you *want* to use dynamic linking.  Is the DLL in question a managed DLL (native .net objects), COM, or native?  If COM, are you registering it on the client machine?

Comment: Unfortunately I am very new to dynamic linking, so please bear with me. I am not sure which one it is, but I do know the library is built to usable across the .net platform, and it controls a I/O interface for lab equipment. How could I go about figuring out which type? Or a better question, are there any good tutorials or any good reading material someone could link me to? Thank you.

Comment: Assuming this is a .NET DLL, have you tried just including it in the output folder alongside your project's assembly (generally the .exe)?

Comment: Yes, I have included it in the output folder.

Comment: if you don't know which one it is, how would you include in "compilation"?

Answer (score 0):

The default setting of .NET Framework is to load native libraries from system paths, not current directory.

But you might learn from `System.Data.SQLite` project (open source), so as to pre-loading native libraries from current folder, and based on OS bitness,

http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

Although generating a mixed mode assembly (native and managed bits are merged) sounds like a better solution, System.Data.SQLite users often are confused. Thus, I recommend the pre-loading approach.